# How to add extra parameter with full url in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a url with some query string. I know I can get the full string with `url()->full()`. But I want to add extra query string with it. And there I am facing problem.

So far I have tried, `href={{ url()->full()."&rating=5" }}` This is working fine if there is already some query data in the url. But if there is none then it is showing error.

Example: If my url is `example.com/147?place=33` then it works but if my url is `example.com/147` then it doesn't work.

I also tried, `href={{ url()->full()."?rating=5" }}`. This is working only in the opposite scenario.

How can I **append** my own query string after the full url regardless of the existence of current query?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As suggested from @joão-henrique-silveira I add my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762882/how-to-add-extra-parameter-with-full-url-in-laravel-blade/54762941?noredirect=1#comment103575269_54762941) as an answer for better visibility.

```
{{ request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['foo' => 'bar']) }}
```

Comment: I love Laravel.

Comment: same as url()->request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['foo' => 'bar'])

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like:

```
href={{ url()->current().'?'.http_build_query(array_merge(request()->all(),['rating' => 5])) }}
```

This is just appending the extra parameter in the current request input and then rebuilding the query string.

Comment: It doesn't work if there is already 'rating' in the query. For example, if my url is 'example.com/147?rating=5' then it doesn't work for 'example.com/147?rating=3'

Comment: @NabilFarhan changed it to `array_merge` so that the 2nd array entries always overwrite the first

Comment: A little easier to read would be: {{ request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['foo' => 'bar']) }}

Comment: @superfly add your comment as an answer to people looking for it in the future. It's much better and easier